# Changing assets between releases

Tags: android, assets, release

Does anyone know if the old assets get removed from the assets folder when an app is re-released / updated on the Play Store? I want to include an new and updated database with my re-releases, but really don't want the out of date ones taking up space on the users' phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't get removed if you made any changes in assets folder, while creating the release APK delete the build folder and create the APK.

Comment: I tried removing the 'build' folder before rebuilding and running my app, and it did indeed remove my old assets files! Thank you so much :D